# Passing data to Detail View, actual data or reference ID

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, architecture, uicollectionview

## Situation

Let’s say there is an iPhone app that shows articles.  Articles are loaded from a server.

It has two views.

- TableView: Shows list of articles
- DetailView: Shows detail of selected article

## Problem / Question

I want to know better way of passing data from TableView to Detail View.

Which one of the following is a better practice?

#### Option 1

Pass an actual Article object from TableView to DetailView

DetailView just displays the Article

#### Option 2

Pass reference ID of Article from TableView to DetailView

This case, the DetailView loads the article from server by the ID of the Article.

Option2 seems a better design since relation between TableView and DetailView is minimum.

Option1 seems a little bit faster since i doesn’t have to connect to API ever time it loads an article

I understand it depends on situation but i would like to know if there is any reasonable guideline.

Comment: I would use option 1. If you already have the article why would you back to the network?

Comment: In very simple situations, definitely option 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a combo of both since many apps such as Facebook also do the same. For eg. if I have a photo that has likes in my notification bar, I can click on that photo and see it even if I do not have an active connection at that time. I will obviously be shown the older data. However at that time, Facebook immediately sends a call to the server and the updated likes are shown.

Therefore it should be ideal to pass the entire object to the next VC and immediately send an async call to the server. Any changes should then be reloaded in your complete data model. Hope this helps :)